# Git wants to add all untracked repos from one folder back

Tags: git

This might be tricky to explain but I'll try my best.

I have a folder named `git` on my computer that contains all my individual repos. For the sake of this, let's say I have 26 repos named `a` to `z`, and repos `e, g, j, and x` are untracked.

I'm trying to `git add -i` while in the folder for repo `x`, but Git wants to add **ALL** of the files from repos `e, g, and j` in addition to `x`.

I don't understand what's going on and don't know how to fix this. I'm expecting that only files for `x` would try to be tracked by running this command. If that's not how that works, is there a way to narrow it down to just `x`?

Hopefully my explanation makes sense and one of you can guide me in the right direction!

Comment: Why are you tracking entire repos inside another repo? Did you mean to use submodules?

Comment: The folder `git` contains only the repos but is not a repo itself.

Comment: What does _"repos [...] are untracked"_ mean then? If you're not in a repo, there's no such thing as tracked or untracked

Comment: That local changes have been made in this repo.

Comment: Did you have a `.git` folder in your folder `git`?

Comment: Please may you address our comments? Otherwise our answers are just going to be guesses.

Answer (score 0):

man [git add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) says:

> -i, --interactive
> Add modified contents in the working tree interactively to the index. Optional path arguments may be supplied to limit operation to a subset of the working tree.

So, if you give a path to the command, only a subset of the working tree will be concerned.

Comment: But we don't know if the OP is even in a git repo?

Comment: If OP didn't git init, he should get this error  "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git ", right?

Comment: then the issue is, why is the OP using git repo's inside another without using submodules?